# Issue with Powershell 5.1 not copying over files with specified extensions, but does copy over directory structure

Tags: windows, powershell, server, file-copying

I am currently working on just some personal powershell 5.1 scripts. Ideally, I have two machines set up, one that is local (I'll call it source), and one that is remote (I'll call it destination). The source system has a certain file directory structure with various files. I've been wanting to copy over that exact directory, maintaining the structure to the destination server. I have two conditions that I am trying to maintain, to copy the source files to the destination location if the destination location does not have those files or, copy the source files to the destination if and only if the most recently modified time is earlier than that on the destination server (copying only files with specific extensions and ignoring the rest).
The issue that I am having now is that while the actual directory structure is being copied over from source to destination, the actual files with data (like .xml, .pem, etc) files are no where to be found. They are not being copied over and I have spent the better half of 10 hours trying to figure out why. I will post the code below.

```
foreach ($fileS1 in Get-ChildItem $RootFolder -Recurse) {
    $FolderNameS1 = $fileS1.FullName
    $FolderNameNewS1 = $fileS1.FullName

    # check if the path on the remote session exists
    $ValidPathS1 = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock { 
        Test-Path -Path $using:FolderNameNewS1 
    } 

    If ($ValidPathS1 -eq $False) {
        #create the folder structure
        if ($fileS1.PSIsContainer -eq $True) {
            Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock { 
                New-Item -Path $using:FolderNameNewS1 -ItemType Directory -Verbose
            } 
        }
    }

    # Get the files in the source folder
    $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem $FolderNameS1 -Recurse
    # Get the files in the destination folder
    $destinationFiles = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ChildItem $using:FolderNameNewS1 -Recurse
    }

    # Compare the last write time of each source file with the last write time of its corresponding destination file
    $extensions = "p12", "properties", "pem"
    foreach ($sourceFile in $sourceFiles) {
        if($extensions -contains $sourceFile.Extension){
            $fileCopied = $False
            # check if the file on the remote session exists
                $destinationFilePath = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock {
                $destFilePath = Join-Path $using:FolderNameNewS1 $using:sourceFile.Name
                if(!(Test-Path $destFilePath)){
                    New-Item -Path $destFilePath -ItemType File -Force
                }
                return $destFilePath
                }
            if($destinationFilePath -ne ""){
                $destinationFile = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock {
                    Get-Item $using:destinationFilePath
                }
    
                $remoteFileExist = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock { 
                Test-Path $using:destinationFilePath
                }

            if(!$remoteFileExist){
                Copy-Item $sourceFile.FullName -Destination $FolderNameNewS1  -ToSession $Session1 -Force -Verbose 
                }
            else{
            $remoteLastWriteTime = Invoke-Command -Session $Session1 -ScriptBlock { 
            (Get-Item $using:destinationFilePath).LastWriteTime
                }
            $remoteLastWriteTime = $remoteLastWriteTime.ToLocalTime()
            # Compare the last write time of source file and destination file
            if ($sourceFile.LastWriteTime -gt $remoteLastWriteTime) {
            #copy only the files with the specified extensions
            if($extensions -contains $sourceFile.Extension){
            Copy-Item $sourceFile.FullName -Destination $FolderNameNewS1  -ToSession $Session1 -Force -Verbose 
            $fileCopied = $True
        }
    }
}
            if ($fileCopied -eq $True) {
                #remove the source file
               # Remove-Item $sourceFile.FullName -Force -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                $fileCopied = $False
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I am using PSSession to remote into the destination server, and we can assume that $RootFolder contains the entire directory.

Comment: Why do you need a PSSession to remote into the destination server? Can you not access the destination folder using its UNC name? (`\\remoteServer\Share\Folderpath`)? Wouldn't using robocopy be faster/easier?

Comment: Unfortunately I am restricted to using Copy-Item